# Adding tutorial data to R package gives error when using devtools::test()

Tags: r, r-package

I'm creating an r-package and want to add example data within the package. So I've created a folder that I've called data; but as soon as I add my tutorialdata.RData file and run the test routine `devtools::test()` I get the following error:

Loading text
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
Calls:  ...  -> load_data -> unlist -> lapply -> FUN
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘sq_data_tutorial.RData’ has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated 
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

I have tried to manually open the files with `readRDS()` and that works fine. (and when I remove the files from the folder, it all works fine again).

Comment: you need `usethis::use_data()`

Comment: Thanks, that worked usethis::use_data(DATA_TO_BE_SAVED)